# Solr: is caching of scale boost function results possible?

Tags: performance, caching, boost, solr

In our use-case we boost products by the number of purchases like this:

```
boost=scale(topseller, 1, 5)
```

Because we have other factors that play into the document score we use the scale function to maximize the boost value to 5, this works fine but is expensive regarding the query time. The result of the function doesn´t seem to get cached and each query calculates it anew. Is there a way to cache the result or another (query-time) alternative with the same result but better performance? We would like to avoid a pre-calculation of the boost value on index time if possible.

Comment: Would the filter cache be of any help? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache

Comment: Sadly not, we have this active but it seems it is not working for this specific function boost. We went with precalculating the boost value on index time, which resulted on average in 8 times faster queries, so be aware.